# GetStream IO - Create "Discover" like feeds

Tags: getstream-io

I've been working with GetStream this week and it worked as expected for the first part. However, now that I would like to move forward, I would like to create a "discover like" (like the one on Instagram by example?) feature

The thing is, I am not really sure how to achieve it. My end goal would be something like:

- You have posts (from users I don't follow) in the Discover feed of the userA
- UserA follow a user from the discover (owner of a post, let say UserX)
- UserX activities (previous and future ones) gets forwarded to userA flat feed and disappear from discover feed for the UserA

This would means (from my understanding) following everyone when a user create an account, and then unfollow people from discover flat feed (on follow) and follow them from timeline flat feed? But it seems to be unscalable to me, isn't it?...

For now, I have 2 feeds:
- users-timeline -> flat feed containing user post (post of UserA by example)
- followings-timeline -> flat feed which follows activities on selected "users-timelines"

How could I have a third feed which would act as a discover?

Comment: I have a similar use case? @Emixam23, have you managed to come up with a solution?

Comment: Yes... what i did is that i created flat_fleed for each user (discover_flat_feed_ID_USER) and made this flat feed follow randomly people at the beginning (because of our use). The issue is that i couldn't come up with a 100% getstream IO solution for our feed system as our app was really specific.. Now with experience on this sytème, i think that if you use a basic feed app, getstream is definitely your solution. If not, then database such as Cassandra/Kubernetes with background work for post/item replication is more a way to go :)